# 'docker-compose up' as a Different User Without Recreating Containers

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, devops

A `docker-compose.yml` file was used to create a number of Docker containers by having user `foo` run `docker-compose up -d`. However, user `foo` is scheduled for deletion and we want a different user `bar` to be in charge to running these same containers. The `docker-compose.yml` file along with the mounted volumes must now be moved to a different location as well.

Is it possible now for user `bar` to take over control of the existing Docker containers, instead of having user `foo` perform `docker-compose down` and have user `bar` copy all the files to the new location, then run `docker-compose up -d`?

This way we will avoid having to redo setup steps in the newly created Docker containers created by user `bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker doesn't have any concept of "user".  Anyone who can reach the Docker daemon can perform any operation on any container.

In a Compose context, things are generally keyed off of a project name, which defaults to the name of the current directory.  So if the project was previously in `/home/foo/projects/thing`, running `docker-compose` commands from `/home/bar/projects/thing` should find the same containers, volumes, and networks.  (And if there are relative-path bind-mounts, it will want to move them to the new base directory.)